# Sci-Fi short story telepath uses CAPITAL LETTERS

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It was in a collection of Sci-Fi short stories which I lent to a friend and never got back.

It was about a human who somehow became trapped in a muddy cave or beneath the ground. There the man encountered a being that was humanoid, large, and had black skin more like a shiny shell. The most memorable feature of this being was that it was telepathic, it communicated with the man IN CAPITAL LETTERS to signify it was non-verbal communication.

The mental communication hurt the man to receive. It became a sort of mental combat or test the human had to pass before he could be released.

Comment: Can you give us an estimate of when you read this?

Comment: Was the story set on earth or another planet?

Comment: I read it about 2001, 2002. I recall it being set on earth. Thank you!

Comment: was the earth flat by any chance? :D